# add_tooltip in ggvis with ioslides

Tags: r, knitr, ggvis

I'm trying to add a ggvis plot with a tooltip to an ioslides presentation using knitr:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r options}
library(knitr)
```
## Slide with ggvis plot

```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(ggvis)
cars %>%
  ggvis(~speed, ~dist) %>% 
  layer_points(fill.hover := "red") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data) data$dist)
```
````

If I plot the graph in RStudio the tooltip shows up properly in the Viewer, but when I knit it to html, only the fill.hover works, and no tooltip shows up.

Comment: If your interactivity is limited to displaying tooltpis you may consider the ggplot2 extension ggiraph, which plays well in ioslides (http://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/introduction.html).